# Scanning Computer and displaying files in listbox?

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

Ok, i have some code that will scan my computer and find .txt files and display them in a listbox:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     IEnumerable<string> files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\", "*.txt*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}", f)); 
        }
    }
```

I get an error every time i run this. It says i do not authorization to the trash bin. I do not care weather it scans the trash or not. It there any way to exclude the trash bin out of the scan? Also, can someone help me improve my code, if you see anything wrong! Thanks!

Comment: out of interest - if you do a search from explorer are the results you get acceptable?  If so, you might consider [Windows Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684395(v=vs.85).aspx)  If you google around you will find numerous examples of accessing from C#

Comment: well is there a way to bypass the authorization thing???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickest way is to put them under a try-catch block because `EnumerateFiles` function does not have access to the restricted files because of the operating system permissions.

```
  private void SearchDrives()
  {
     foreach (String drive in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
     {
        try
        {
           // Search for folders into the drive.
           SearchFolders(drive);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
     }
  }
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  private void SearchFolders(String prmPath)
  {
     try
     {
        foreach (String folder in Directory.GetDirectories(prmPath))
        {
           // Recursive call for each subdirectory.
           SearchFolders(folder);

           // Create the list of files.
           SearchFiles(folder);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception) { }
  }
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  private void SearchFiles(String prmPath)
  {
     try
     {
        foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles(prmPath))
        {
           FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
           if (info.Extension == ".txt")
           {
              listBox1.Items.Add(info.Name); 
           }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception) { }
  }
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Not just the recycle bin, it will also fail to read the file header of several files into your system direcotry.

Comment: Ok, i really like this answer...but when i click the button, nothing happens...nothing? Why is that?

Comment: @EliteGamer: Try the new example that I used once in my program to search the entire hard drive. The process works, but the complexity depends on the number of subfolders and files from your path and the number exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can do it so that you do recursive calls for every folder and just use try/catch blocks to see witch ones you can or can't access. But as Andras suggested I would also go with what allready exists will save you time

[Another aproach on your example](http://java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0300__File-Directory-Stream/Traverseallfilesundertheroot.htm)